# What does "compares less than zero" mean?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, terminology

I have posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498486/what-does-compares-0-mean) on Stack Overflow about a curious usage of the verb "to compare" in a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r2.pdf) I read:

> The expression **a <=> b** returns an object that compares **<0** if **a < b**,
>   compares **>0** if **a > b**, and compares **==0** if a and b are
>   equal/equivalent.

Translation:

> The expression **blah-blah** returns an object that compares less than zero if blah-blah...

Does this sentence make sense in English? Is this some kind of jargon used by programmers? Is it even grammatical and makes any sense? If so, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: It’s more or less understandable in context as meaning “evaluates to less than zero”, but it’s certainly not something I’ve ever seen before. It may be more or less conventional jargon in C++-speak, but I don’t remember coming across it before. Then again, I don’t know the first thing about C++, so I wouldn’t be likely to know that.

Comment: Thank you!! I am so glad I asked! Can you give me a definitive answer based exclusively on English grammar?

Comment: ... English grammar often tends to be in dispute rather than able to provide definitive answers. Different registers accept different usages.

Comment: The language here is a bit odd. A better explanation can be found at https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/spaceship-operator/. The operator does:

(a <=> b) < 0  //true if a < b, or
(a <=> b) > 0  //true if a > b, or
(a <=> b) == 0 //true if a is equal/equivalent to b.
You compare the result of the spaceship operator to 0, but I don't think that it's natural to say it "compares <0". That sounds like bad documentation.

Answer (score 1):

*P* compares less than zero means:  evaluating the statement "*P* < 0" returns "true".  It could be that the "object" *P* is a number which is less than zero, or it could be that it is not a number at all but some other type of object which (by convention) has this property.

Comment: "This property"  meaning that (by definition) comparison of this object with some number, at least with 0, is a valid operation with the value "true" in the defined cases.